# Copy/Paste Text box ends up way off screen in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, text

I'm trying to copy/paste some drawing text box elements in data view to preserve the formatting and for some reason it's pasting the element way out of my view area and way outside the scale of my drawing.

Is this a projection issue?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that my annotation group coordinate system didn't match my data frame. To fix this, right click on your data frame, Properties, Annotation Groups tab, then set coordinate system to match.

Comment: THANK YOU for following up on this.  I've been annoyed by this for some time.  I wasn't even paying attention to there *being* a separate annotation coordinate system.